# Swift 3 method to create utf8 encoded Data from String

Tags: string, utf-8, swift3

I know there's a bunch of pre Swift3 questions regarding NSData stuff. I'm curious how to go between a Swift3 `String` to a utf8 encoded (with or without null termination) to Swift3 `Data` object.

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
let input = "Hello World"
let terminatedData = Data(bytes: Array(input.nulTerminatedUTF8))
let unterminatedData = Data(bytes: Array(input.utf8))
```

Having to do the intermediate `Array()` construction seems wrong.

Comment: Would you agree that this question should be reviewed again as accepted answer uses NSFoundation API instead of Swift one?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's simple:

```
let input = "Hello World"
let data = input.data(using: .utf8)!
```

If you want to terminate `data` with null, simply `append` a 0 to it. Or you may call `cString(using:)`

```
let cString = input.cString(using: .utf8)! // null-terminated
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. Amusingly, the `cString` method returns a `[UInt8]`

Comment: If this answered your question satisfactorily, please mark it as the correct answer. This encourages more in the community to answer your questions and ensures that when other users stumble onto this page with the same question, they can easily find the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

`NSString` methods from `NSFoundation` framework should be dropped in favor for Swift Standard Library equivalents. Data can be initialized with any `Sequence` which elements are `UInt8`. `String.UTF8View` satisfies this requirement.

```
let input = "Hello World"
let data = Data(input.utf8)
// [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

String null termination is an implementation detail of C language and it should not leak outside. If you are planning to work with C APIs, please take a look at the `utf8CString` property of `String` type:

```
public var utf8CString: ContiguousArray<CChar> { get }
```

`Data` can be obtained after `CChar` is converted to `UInt8`:

```
let input = "Hello World"
let data = Data(input.utf8CString.map { UInt8($0) })
// [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 0]
```